# How to set Google Maps Directions in my own google map application?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display direction in my own application i don't want like this .. How to get direction in my own map ? PLease help me

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Search on _google_ `> 100` solutions available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use google directions api for this purpose. A useful tutorial is provided in this link 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get directions using just the Google Maps V2 api. You should use the Google Directions API direction request call. This will return the raw direction data in json which would allow you to draw a Polyline for the directions on the map or show the data in any format you would like.